# How does config file in lightbend/config works?

Tags: java, scala, config

I'm having trouble with the substitution using [lightbend config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library .

I have an application.conf file with this content:

```
   property.a = "propA"
    list = 
    [
        {
            nameProp=one,
            propToReplace = ${property.a}
        },
        {
            nameProp=two,
            propToReplace  = ${property.a}
        }
    ]

    some.env {
       property.a = "propEnvironment"
    }
```

At some point in the code, I'm loading the property file using Configuration.load().
My goal is to subtitute the **propToReplace** with the value of property.a inside **some.env**, but after I run it I gets replace for the value outside (**property.a = "propA"**).

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute it by using **environment variables**, like running your program with:

```
-Dproperty.a=mySubstituteValue
```